# posting data from my ionic/angular.js app to laravel 5.2 database gives error

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, ionic-framework, cors

view

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="splash padding has-header">
<p class="button button-calm  button-block" ng-click="insert()">post</p>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller
    $scope.insert = function() {
            var data = {matric:21};

```
  $http.post("http://localhost:8000/datas",data).success(function(data,status){
    console.log(data);
  }).error(function(error){
    console.log("error is that ",error);
  });
};
```

laravel routes

```
Route::get('datas',array('middleware' => 'cors', 'uses' => 'datasController@index'));
Route::get('datas/{level}',array('middleware' => 'cors', 'uses' => 'datasController@show'));
Route::post('datas',array('middleware' => 'cors', 'uses' => 'datasController@store'));
```

laravel controller

```
 public function store()
    {
        $dat = new Data();
        $dat->matric = input::get('matric');
        $dat->save();
    }
```

the error i get in my chrome log

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:8000/datas`. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values
>   'http://evil.com/, *', but only one is allowed. Origin
>   `'http://localhost:8100'` is therefore not allowed access.
>
> controllers.js:126 error is that  null

the error i get in my mozilla log

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/datas. (Reason: CORS
>   header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). error is that  null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran a post request through postman and saw a verifycrsf tokken error.you can get through this by editin the verifycrsf.php file in your laravel file,add your paths to the function there and it should work.
(for example. 'api/*' for localhost:8000/api/matric)

Comment: This tripped me up too for a while - this was the workaround for me in Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) package, it will help you with the Cross Origin Request Protection